# Use (asynchronous) $http result to (synchronously) check permissions on routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to check permissions on routes in an AngularJS application. Routes are handled by angular-ui-router.

My routes and permissions-per-route are defined as this:

```
angular.module('my_app')
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'content.html',
            resolve: {
                user_info: function (UserService) {
                    return UserService.user_info();
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root.some_page', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'some_page.html',
            controller: 'home',
            data: {
              roles: ['some_right', 'some_other_right]
            }
        });
}
```

I then check for permissions as this:

```
[...].run(function ($rootScope, $state, UserService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function (event, toState) {
            if (!!toState.data) {
                var required_roles = toState.data.roles;
                if (!UserService.has_permission_in(required_roles)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('root.access_forbidden');
                }
            }
        });
});
```

All good for now. My issue is resolving user permissions. There are provided by a backend and fetched using `$http.get(...)`. Since the `$http` service returns a promise, it don't always have the result when the `$stateChangeStart` is event triggered.

It's "good" when the application is "warm", but if I land on a protected page, it fails (the data are not ready). I have no way to "wait" for the promise.

What would be a "good" way of doing access control on routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your protected state's definition:

```
.state('root.some_page', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'some_page.html',
            controller: 'home',
            resolve: {
             access: function($http, $state){ //Note: you can inject your own services/factories too
             var requiredPermissions = ['some_right', 'some_other_right'];
              return $http.get(...).then(function(response){
               var permissions = response.data.permissions;
               var granted = permissions.reduce((prev,curr) => requiredPermissions.indexOf(curr) > -1 || prev, false);
               if(!granted)
                $state.go('publicState');
               return permissions;
              });
             }
            }
        })
```

**Resolve** waits for promises to settle before moving to a new state.

Better:

```
function checkPermissions(requiredPermissions){
 return function ($http, $state){ //Note: you can inject your own services/factories too
              return $http.get(...).then(function(response){
               var permissions = response.data.permissions;
               var granted = permissions.reduce((prev,curr) => requiredPermissions.indexOf(curr) > -1 || prev, false);
               if(!granted)
                $state.go('publicState');
               return permissions;
              });
             }
 }

 //In state definition
.state('root.some_page', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'some_page.html',
        controller: 'home',
        resolve: {
         access: checkPermissions(['first','second'])
        }
    })
```

Comment: That sounds nice, thanks. But if I have many protected routes, that would mean I have to duplicate all this code for all my states?

Comment: Or create a function that takes as an argument a list of permissions and returns a function that validates against these permissions. I'll edit my answer.